# Sentinels of the Multiverse crash

Tags: technical-issues, sentinels-of-the-multiverse

So I downloaded Sentinels of the Multiverse on my Kindle Fire. For the first few games, it played beautifully, if occasionally a little slow. Since then (and since I've bought the expansions), the game crashes out every turn or so. In the last few hours, it's gotten so bad I can't get a game started before it quits out.

I've tried turning off all animations, but it hasn't helped. Is this a known problem? Are there any solutions to get the game running consistently?

Best I can tell, I've got the 2nd edition 8.9" Fire HD

### Kindle Fire HD 2nd Gen Specs

- **Memory:** 8GB Internal Flash Storage
- **CPU:** 1.2GHz Dual Core
- **RAM:** 1GB

Comment: It's probably important to list which Kindle Fire you are trying to play this on as the specs differ a little. That said I did a quick google search and found that people had some issues on devices with lower amounts of RAM.

Comment: The user @Josh writes that he has found similar issues being experienced with models of lower RAM. Could you tell us the model number of your device?

Comment: Reading the question in full, it sounds like your problems have come out of installing the expansions, which from a technical point of view backs Josh' thoughts. We sell those things at work, and would never recommend them for game apps

Comment: Kindle stats added to the question

Comment: I do not have time to post a quality answer, but if I get home and its not here, I will try. But my recommendation is that you should not be playing games on that Kindle to begin with. Containing a mere 1GB of RAM, in which some of it will not be free (everything being done by the kindle including its operating system is using up some of the RAM), you would expect to have memory issues running games. I stay away from games unless I have at least 2GB of RAM on my device. As I said, this is just my recommendation. I may be wrong, but Ill check when I get home.

Comment: in the mean time, try finding a memory management app. It is likely you have other apps open using the ram. You would be surprised how often people report "broken slow phones" to me at work, only for me to find its because they have all these apps in the background they never use, or did not know even existed.